# Scroll not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, selenium-webdriver

I tried scroll(x,y) using javascript in Internet Explorer 10 . But, it did not work when I tried executing the script for a website. What is the equivalent for the same in IE ? It's a part of a Java Selenium test. I need to scroll in the page. So, I do that by executing a javascript code by using javascript executor.

```
for(int i=0;i<X;i+=Y)   
String cmd = "window.scrollTo(0,"+i+")";    
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(cmd);
```

I use the above code in my test to scroll the page. But, in Internet Explorer IE10 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos)`. This works in all major browsers, read about the function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp).

Comment: Are you sure it works ? I tried it for IE10 but it doesn't work ?

Comment: Yes, it works. You should post code from your project you probably made a different problem. @user3209160

Comment: I'm running a javascript code from a java selenium test by using a javascript executor.

Comment: My code is like : ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+i+""); and i increments in a for loop

Comment: @user3209160 post as much relevant code as you can **in your question as an edit**

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try to `scrollIntoView` the element like this

```
JavascriptExecutor jse=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById(<id>).scrollIntoView(true)");
```

Faced similar issue. This works for me as an alternative for `window.scrollTo` JS method in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but with IE 9.

I found that

```
executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,100)")
```

did not work, but

```
executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,100);")
```

did work. Note the ";" at the end of the executed command.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are issues with JavascriptExecutor in certain versions of IE10. [Here](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2015/02/03/selenium-ie-10-javascript-stack-trace-information-error/) provides a possible workaround but I have not tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below method for scrolling in case of Internet explorer (where element is the reference of WebElement, which needs to be scrolled to center of screen):

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-300)", "");
```

For other browsers, I am using:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: \"center\"});", element);
```

Both of these will scroll the element to center of screen.

Do not forget to replace the desired locator instead of **element**.